# How do I evenly space numbers from an array in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm doing an assignment on Image Filtering using gray scale numbers (0-256). I've created an array of 16x16 and I need to evenly space the columns so they format as more of pixels on an image much like a table. I'm newer to coding so not sure what code I should include as there is a decent bit. Formatting on here might change the look of the code but anything helps. Towards the end at for print_image is where I assume I could enter std::cout or std:setw() but I'm not sure.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib> // Random support
#include <iomanip> // I/O Manipulation support


#define MIN_RANDOM_NUMBER 0
#define MAX_RANDOM_NUMBER 256

#define ROWS 16
#define COLS 16

using namespace std;

void print_image(unsigned char image[][COLS], int nRows) 
{
  for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++){
      cout << (int) image[row][col] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}

void initialize_random_image(unsigned char image[][COLS], int nRows, int min_value, int max_value)
{
  for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++){
      image[row][col] = rand() % (MAX_RANDOM_NUMBER-MIN_RANDOM_NUMBER) + MIN_RANDOM_NUMBER;
    }
  }
}

void filter_image(unsigned char ImageIn[][COLS], int nRows,
                  unsigned char ImageOut[][COLS],
                  char ApplyFilter[3][3])
{
  for (int row = 1; row < ROWS-1; row++) {
    for (int col = 1; col < COLS-1; col++){
        int sum = ImageIn[row-1][col-1] * ApplyFilter[0][0]+
                                ImageIn[row-1][col] * ApplyFilter[0][1]+
                                ImageIn[row-1][col+1] * ApplyFilter[0][2]+
                                ImageIn[row][col-1] * ApplyFilter[1][0]+
                                ImageIn[row][col] * ApplyFilter[1][1]+
                                ImageIn[row][col+1] * ApplyFilter[1][2]+
                                ImageIn[row+1][col-1] * ApplyFilter[2][0]+
                                ImageIn[row+1][col] * ApplyFilter[2][1]+
                                ImageIn[row+1][col+1] * ApplyFilter[2][2];
      
        if (sum > 255)
          sum; 255;
            ImageOut[row][col] = (unsigned char) sum;

    }
  }  
}

int main()
{
  unsigned char ImageInput[ROWS][COLS];
  unsigned char ImageOutput[ROWS][COLS]; 
  
  
  char Filter[3][3] = { {0,-1,0}, {-1,5,-1}, {0,-1,0} };


  srand(13);


  cout << setw(25) << "Original" << endl;
  print_image(ImageInput,ROWS);


  filter_image(ImageInput, ROWS, ImageOutput, Filter);
  
  
  cout << setw(25) << "Filtered" << endl;
  print_image(ImageOutput,ROWS);
}
```

Comment: Also worth looking at C++ [Pseudo-random number generation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) (most individual links show examples for use)

Answer (score 1):

Change your print_image function and use `setw` to print the image pixel values in proper tabular format. Also, use `static_cast` instead of C-style casts.

```
void print_image(unsigned char image[][COLS], int nRows) 
{
  for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
      // set the width of the next field to 4 (one space and three digits)
      cout << setw(4) << static_cast<int>(image[row][col]);
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}
```